# Why did the Three Blind Mice get 'into character' so early?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, dr-no

The [Three Blind Mice](http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/The_Three_Blind_Mice) are seen at the end of the opening scene of *Dr. No* maneuvering their way "blindly" through the streets of Kingston, Jamaica. They are not actually blind.

They eventually come to the country club where Strangways is playing cards and murder him in the driveway after he gives them a small donation.

Why did they have to pretend to be blind all the way to the country club? Why not just walk there like the typical pedestrian and then put on the ruse once they reached the driveway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that it's not just about getting close to their target but also not tipping off passers-by about their identity. Given how noticeable they are (in terms of there being three of them, as well as their unusual racial mix), pretending to be blind allows them to travel to Richmond Road without attracting unwarranted attention.

> Just before six-fifteen, the silence of Richmond Road was softly
>   broken. Three blind beggars came round the corner of the intersection
>   and moved slowly down the pavement towards the four cars. They were
>   Chigroes—Chinese Negroes—bulky men, but bowed as they shuffled along,
>   tapping at the kerb with their white sticks. They walked in file. The
>   first man, who wore blue glasses and could presumably see better than
>   the others, walked in front holding a tin cup against the crook of the
>   stick in his left hand. The right hand of the second man rested on his
>   shoulder and the right hand of the third on the shoulder of the
>   second. The eyes of the second and third men were shut. The three men
>   were dressed in rags and wore dirty jippa-jappa baseball caps with
>   long peaks. They said nothing and no noise came from them except the
>   soft tapping of their sticks as they came slowly down the shadowed
>   pavement towards the group of cars.
>
> The three blind men would not have been incongruous in Kingston, where
>   there are many diseased people on the streets, but, in this quiet rich
>   empty street, they made an unpleasant impression. And it was odd that
>   they should all be Chinese Negroes. This is not a common mixture of
>   bloods.
>   <sub><sub>- Dr No. Ian Fleming</sub></sub>

Let us imagine that Strangway or one of his associates were to pass these three gentlemen walking along *normally* on their way to the club, then to see them a few minutes later pretending to be blind. One can envision that that would instantly cause suspicion.